# Are there Nirnroots in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Oblivion had a unique kind of plant placed across Cyrodill, the [Nirnroot](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Nirnroot).

As opposed to other plants that you could find in the game, this one did not regrow after time, and there was also a quest attached to it, which had you collect all 100 Nirnroots that were hidden in the lands.

From a gameplay perspective it was a nice distraction from the usual questing - Oblivion (and as far as I know other ES games as well) didn't have that many "collectible" quests.

So, will there be Nirnroots in Skyrim?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, there will be Nirnroots in Skyrim:
[image: Nirnroot]
This image is from the G4TV Skyrim demo. You can also see Nirnroot in the Skyrim Trailer.
You can find information about its alchemical properties, location, quests and lore on the [Elder Scrolls Wiki Nirnroot](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Nirnroot_%28Skyrim%29) page.

Answer (score 4):

Yes they are in game and you can still collect them(Listen for that familiar Nirnroot humming). You can also find a farm that grows it!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Nirnroot will be making a return.

> Nirnroot appears in the new Skyrim trailer, and shown in the item menu during the G4TV Skyrim demo.

[Source](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Nirnroot)

Answer (score 1):

Yes but it is not yet confirmed whether or not the nirnroots will be usable in general potion making or just part of a quest like in Oblivion.

Comment: I collected a Nirnroot and had no quests pop up.

Answer (score 1):

They can be used in alchemy. Someone in riften wanted me to collect some ingredients and part of what i need to get is 20 nirnroots.

I don't know yet if they grow back or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of Nirnroots in the game; also, in some special places (details in the spoiler section below) you'll find a new plant — Crimson Nirnroot. Both plants cast some special sound, which you can use to find them more effectively.

> I encountered Nirnroots in the underground dungeon that was part of the quest for obtaining the Elder Scroll. Never saw them enywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

So far I've found two Nirnroots. They glow in the dark and emit a soft humming. I don't know if they're used for anything or if there's a quest that goes with them yet, though.

Comment: You can use them to make potions.(Alchemy)

Answer (score 0):

There are two different varieties of Nirnroot in Skyrim. The first is the same from Oblivion and is now more common and used as a commmon ingredient.

The second,

> Crimson Nirnroot, is the Nirnroot that you will need to collect for quests and can only be found in the underground area of Blackreach which is accessed by elevators in the bottom of several Dwarven or "Dweamer" ruins scattered throughout the world.